# Символ $ в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Что делает символ `$` в MySQL, или как он работает? 
Например, я могу успешно вставить в поле таблицы значение

```
$UNIX_TIMESTAMP(archive_date) * 1000
```

а когда пытаюсь вставить это же выражение без символа `$`,

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(archive_date) * 1000
```

получаю ошибку:

> Unknown column 'archive_date' in 'field list'

Получается, этот символ экранирует функции, или у него какое-то другое значение?

**UPD**

То, что "я могу успешно вставить в поле таблицы значение" - это не гипотетическая возможность, у меня на самом деле проходит эта вставка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не можете и вообще непонятно с чего у вас выполняется первая строчка, когда во втором случае бьет ошибку, что отсутствует поле.

**Этот символ ничего не делает непосредственно в MySQL и у него нет никакого назначения.**

При попытке вызвать

```
SELECT $UNIX_TIMESTAMP(archive_date) * 1000 FROM my_table
```

Вы вероятно получите ошибку

```
FUNCTION api.$UNIX_TIMESTAMP does not exist
```

И туже самую ошибку вы получите, если будете делать `INSERT VALUES` и если у вас выполняется `$UNIX_TIMESTAMP`, значит скорее всего у Вас есть самонаписанная функция с таким названием.

Символ доллара можно использовать например в REGEXP. Для экранирования переменных используются backslash.

**UPD:**

Судя по последнему скриншоту, вы строку вставляете в базу, а не функцию.

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ("$UNIX_TIMESTAMP(f2312)*1000")
```

и

```
("$MARS_TIMESTAMP(go)*onemillion")
```

конечно будет работать, это же строка. А вот без кавычек, ничего не вставиться.

Comment: То, что "я могу успешно вставить в поле таблицы значение" - это не гипотетическая возможность, у меня на самом деле проходит эта вставка

Comment: @Ksenia есть возможность снять дамп базы данных с хранимыми процедурами и функциями?

Comment: @Ksenia а код из командной строки MySQL прямо выполняете? Или это PHP код какой-нибудь, где вставлено $str = "SELECT $UNIX_TIMESTAMP...."

Comment: нет, действие происходит в SQLyog'е

Comment: @Ksenia вы строку вставляете в базу, а не функцию, по вашему последнему обновлению поста и INSERT INTO table VALUES ("$UNIX_TIMESTAMP(f2312)*1000") конечно будет работать, это же строка. А вы попробуйте без кавычек, ничего не получиться.

Comment: @Firepro, кстати, теперь всё ещё удивительнее...) при вставке sql-кодом, через `UPDATE`, успешно вставляются и строка "$UNIX_TIMESTAMP(f2312)*1000", и строка "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(f2312)*1000"

Comment: @Ksenia Вы кавычки используете или ваш редактор автоматическй их подставляет, поэтому строка успешно вставляется в таблицу. Чтобы получить именно значение функции нужно убрать кавычки.

Comment: @Firepro, получается, когда я вставляю в таблицу через графический интерфейс строку `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(archive_date) * 1000`, она вставляется не как строка?

Comment: @Ksenia Конечно вставляется как строка, если обернута кавычками то функция никак не обрабатывается. В MYSQL функция UNIX_TIMESTAMP возвращает текущую дату в секундах по unix, и не понятно, зачем вы делаете INSERT этой функции в кавычках, если вам нужно получить ее текущее значение и умножить на 1000. Уберите кавычки и получите корректный результат инсерта:  INSERT INTO table VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()*1000);

Comment: @Firepro, так ведь функция UNIX_TIMESTAMP() может вызываться и с аргументом date - `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)`, и тогда она возвращает величину аргумента как количество секунд с 1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT :)

Comment: И тогда, например, SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2005-10-04 22:23:00') будет возвращать не текущую дату)

Comment: и далее в коде символ $ удаляется и функция UNIX_TIMESTAMP выполняется с аргументом, значение которого подставляется в коде из определённых настроек - таков её смысл тут

Answer (score 1):

В MySQL символ $ не имеет специального значения, возможно у вас определена пользовательская функция `$UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`, которая должна отличать от стандартной функции `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` или дополнять ее какой-то логикой.

Часто символ $ используется для задания альтернативного разделителя запросов в консольной утилите mysql

```
DELIMITER $
```

Этот прием часто используется, чтобы создавать структуры, содержащие в себе несколько запросов, разделенных точкой запятой - хранимые процедуры и функции, триггеры и т.п.

Comment: И про второй вариант - использование этого символа как разделителя - я знаю, но мой случай к нему вроде как никакого отношения не имеет...

Comment: @Ksenia Спасибо, поправил. Поищите функцию $UNIX_TIMESTAMP по дампу - точно такой функции нет?

Comment: нет, в пользовательских функциях такой функции нету

Comment: @Ksenia возможно какие-то расширения установлены? Дело происходит локально или на сервере?

Comment: расширений вроде бы нет... а к базе данных у меня удалённый доступ

Comment: @Ksenia если не сложно выполните запрос SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'test' AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'FUNCTION', подставив вместо test название вашей базы данных - он вернет вам список всех хранимых процедур, просто чтобы точно исключить возможность собственной процедуры.

Comment: @cheops Она делает INSERT этой функции в кавычках....поэтому она у нее выполняется, но вот как выполняется...эх...по скриншоту все станет ясно, который был добавлен...